# New DB a lot slower

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

My work has switched over to a new db. From MySQL 5.5.31 to MariaDB 10.5.4. Now most queries are faster but one query went from 0.3 seconds to 1.6 seconds. When i try explain on both of the queries i get different results.

[Old database explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjGay.png)

[New database explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0W46.png)

Is there some setting i need to change?

The query:

```
SELECT
    aanbieding.id,
    aanbieding.uid,
    aanbieding.vanprijs,
    aanbieding.voorprijs,
    aanbieding.opmerking,
    aanbieding.aantal,
    aanbieding.begindatum,
    aanbieding.einddatum,
    aanbieding.link,
    aanbieding.alleen_online,
    aanbieding.alleen_winkel,
    aanbieding.ppc_feed_uid,
    `aanbieding`.`einddatum` AS `einddatumFormat`,
    DATE_FORMAT(
        (`aanbieding`.`einddatum`),
        '%W %e %M'
    ) AS `einddatumFormat2`,
    DATE_FORMAT(
        (`aanbieding`.`begindatum`),
        '%W %e %M'
    ) AS `begindatumFormat2`,
    ROUND(
        (aanbieding.vanprijs) -(aanbieding.voorprijs),
        2
    ) AS `totalekorting`,
    ROUND(
        100 *(
            (aanbieding.vanprijs) -(aanbieding.voorprijs)
        ) / aanbieding.vanprijs
    ) AS `kortingspercentage`,
    ROUND(
        (aanbieding.voorprijs) /(
            inhoud.aantal_liter * aanbieding.aantal
        ),
        2
    ) AS `prijsperliter`,
    merken.name AS merken_name,
    merken.name_streep AS merken_name_streep,
    inhoud.korte_name AS inhoud_name,
    inhoud.name_streep AS inhoud_name_streep,
    inhoud.korte_name_meervoud AS inhoud_name_meervoud,
    inhoud.aantal_liter,
    soort.uid AS soort_uid,
    soort.name_streep AS soort_name_streep,
    winkel.uid AS winkel_uid,
    winkel.name AS winkel_name,
    winkel.name_streep AS winkel_name_streep,
    winkel.weergeven_aanbieding,
    img_verpak.id AS img_verpak_id,
    img_verpak.name AS img_verpak_name,
    img_verpak.title AS img_verpak_title,
    img_verpak.alt AS img_verpak_alt,
    img_winkel.id AS img_winkel_id,
    img_winkel.name AS img_winkel_name,
    img_winkel.title AS img_winkel_title,
    img_winkel.alt AS img_winkel_alt,
    inhoud_soort.name AS inhoud_soort_name,
    inhoud_soort.name_streep AS inhoud_soort_name_streep,
    inhoud_soort.uid AS inhoud_soort_uid
FROM
    aanbieding
JOIN soort ON aanbieding.`soort__soort_id` = soort.uid AND soort.weergeven = 1 AND soort.deleted = 0
JOIN winkel ON winkel.uid = aanbieding.`winkel__winkel_id` AND winkel.deleted = '0' AND winkel.weergeven = '1'
JOIN merken ON merken.uid = soort.`merken__merken_id` AND merken.deleted = '0' AND merken.weergeven = '1'
JOIN inhoud ON inhoud.uid = soort.`inhoud__inhoud_id` AND inhoud.deleted = '0' AND inhoud.weergeven = '1'
JOIN `fr_images` AS `img_verpak`
ON
    `img_verpak`.`table_id_id` = `soort`.`uid` AND img_verpak.image_settings_id = 53 AND img_verpak.deleted = 0 AND img_verpak.position = 1
JOIN `fr_images` AS `img_winkel`
ON
    `img_winkel`.`table_id_id` = `winkel`.`uid` AND img_winkel.image_settings_id = 108 AND img_winkel.deleted = 0 AND img_winkel.position = 1
JOIN inhoud_soort ON inhoud_soort.uid = inhoud.`soort__inhoud_soort_id` AND inhoud_soort.deleted = 0 AND inhoud_soort.weergeven = 1
WHERE
    aanbieding.deleted = '0' AND aanbieding.weergeven = '1' AND aanbieding.begindatum <= CURDATE() AND(
        aanbieding.einddatum >= CURDATE() OR aanbieding.einddatum IS NULL)
```

Comment: This is a malformed query, because the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` are inconsistent.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you mean with malformed query?

Comment: i thing that the server configuration is is not optimized MariaDB 10.5.4.
Turn the profiling on and post the profiling result of your query.

Comment: If you are joining on table that has a lot of rows, but you will only match on a small %age of them, using a sub-query in the `FROM` is much faster. This may not apply to you, but it may help - https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/mariadb-basics/mariadb-subqueries/

Comment: @kelvinnoordenbos . . . I explained:  The `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` columns are not consistent.  You have a zillion unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` from multiple tables and only one column in the `GROUP BY`.  The query is broken.

Comment: That's one big change to MariaDB, plus 4 major upgrades.  A lot of improvements in the Optimizer.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  We need to see the indexes, at least for aanbieding and winkel.

Answer (score 1):

The explain screenshot of the new setup looks truncated, so not 100% what the tail end of it says, but as a generic explanation:

1. Look at the value of `optimizer_switch` variable on old Nd new server. Establish what is different. Set the new server to the same optimizer_switch settings as the old server. If that results in the same execution plan, bisect your way to the minimal deviation from defaults that produces the old execution plan.
2. If 1) proves insufficient, add index hints (USE INDEX) for each table until you get it to use the old execution plan. Then bisect your way to a minimum set of index hints required to produce the old plan.
3. If 2) still isn't sufficient, use `SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN` instead of just `SELECT`, and change your query so that the tables are listed in the exact same order as in your original fast EXPLAIN.

If after all 3, it still refuse to execute with the original plan, you are out of luck.

Note that 10.5.x isn't ready for production yet, it still has some nasty performance regressions. See:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/07/31/how-mysql-8-0-21-and-mariadb-10-5-4-perform-in-io-bound-scenarios-on-sata-ssd-and-nvme-storage/

and

https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/08/14/evaluating-performance-improvements-in-mariadb-10-5-5/